# Saving solutions of equations with indexed variables to a table

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, table

I am trying to solve a set of equations which are very ugly and have indexed variables. I have a vector of expressions

```
{c[0, 4, 0] + (3221 c[0, 4, 2])/11520 + (5956135 c[0, 4, 4])/
  37158912 + (280835610335 c[0, 4, 6])/1748974436352 + c[2, 0, 0] - (
  47 c[2, 0, 2])/2304 - (24863 c[2, 0, 4])/5308416 - (
  27473615 c[2, 0, 6])/12230590464, 
 23/48 c[0, 4, 2] + (23207 c[0, 4, 4])/55296 + (
  6316272121 c[0, 4, 6])/12145655808 + 23/48 c[2, 0, 2] + (
  5543 c[2, 0, 4])/55296 + (3892727 c[2, 0, 6])/84934656, 
 1/4 c[0, 4, 2] + (689 c[0, 4, 4])/1536 + (57501463 c[0, 4, 6])/
  77856768 + 1/4 c[2, 0, 2] + (433 c[2, 0, 4])/1536 + (
  1288613 c[2, 0, 6])/7077888, 
 23/96 c[0, 4, 4] + (1718215 c[0, 4, 6])/2875392 + 
  23/96 c[2, 0, 4] + (60835 c[2, 0, 6])/221184, 
 1/16 c[0, 4, 4] + (47825 c[0, 4, 6])/159744 + 1/16 c[2, 0, 4] + (
  2645 c[2, 0, 6])/12288, 23/256 c[0, 4, 6] + 23/256 c[2, 0, 6], 
 1/64 c[0, 4, 6] + 1/64 c[2, 0, 6]}
```

which I equate to the vector

```
{494/(6561 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 31579/(51030 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 33529/(
 17010 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 5359/(1701 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 508/(
 189 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 368/(315 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 64/(315 Sqrt[\[Pi]])}
```

and then use `Solve` to solve for the `c[p,q,r]`. The thing is that I would like to save these values, say in a table such that `C[[p,q,r]]` returns me the value `c[p,q,r]` which I obtained above. How can one do this? Note that the number of independent equations in the above are actually less than the number of unknowns so the system is under-constrained. I would like to set the excess number of variables to zero and then get the rest in terms of the ones set to 0 and store that so that I can access them easily.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use Solve to get the solution:

```
sol = First@Solve[{c[0, 4, 0] + ...} == {494/(6561 Sqrt[π]), ...}];
```

Now iterate through the values and put them in another symbol. Instead of putting them in a table, I suggest using downvalues. And I will avoid capital `C` by using `cc` instead:

```
(Evaluate[cc @@ #1] = (#2 /. c[__] -> 0)) & @@@ sol
```

The solutions are now stored inside `cc`.

```
Definition[cc]
(* 
 cc[2, 0, 0] = 429/(4096 Sqrt[π])
 cc[2, 0, 2] = 47/(112 Sqrt[π])
 cc[2, 0, 4] = -(16/(9 Sqrt[π]))
 cc[2, 0, 6] = 4096/(315 Sqrt[π])
*)
```

Comment: Hi @Domen , thanks for the solution. It works as I would like it to. Can you explain what the `Evaluate[cc@@#1]...` bit is doing exactly? I have seen apply and map before but this is new. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! If you simply write `cc@@c[2,0,0] = ...` which is equivalent to `Apply[cc, c[2, 0, 0]] = ...`, Mathematica will complain that you are trying to assign some value to the `Apply`! This is because `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst`. To overcome this, we use `Evaluate` such that `cc@@c[2,0,0]` is evaluated first to `cc[2,0,0]`, and only then `Set` is called to set the value.

Comment: Thanks. @Domen would it be possible to keep the values of the terms that I have set to 0 too? i.e. something like cc[a,b,c] = 0.

Comment: Only for those that were actually present or for any of them? In the second case, you can simply add `cc[__] = 0`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Only those were present, yes.